# I can't find smallest number by this code. How I find smallest number by modifying this code?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, min

Nothing additional errors. I just can't print the smallest input.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Marks of a student(-1 to terminate the inputting marks): ");
    int x=input.nextInt();
    int total=0,large=0,y=0,small=0,z;
    z=x;
    while(x!=-1){
        System.out.print("Marks of a student(-1 to terminate the inputting marks): ");
        x=input.nextInt();
        total+=x;
        y++;
        if(x>=large){
            large=x;
        }
        if(x<small){
            small=x;
        }
    }
    int sum=total+z+1;
    double avg=(double)total/y;
    System.out.println("No of students: "+y);
    System.out.println("Total marks   : "+sum);
    System.out.println("Maximum       : "+large);
    System.out.println("Minimum       : "+small);
    System.out.println("Average       : "+avg);
}
```

Comment: initialize `small` to a large value (such as Integer.MAX_VALUE)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`small` is initialized with `0`, so any input larger than that would be ignored.

One approach is to initialize it with [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE), so any inputted number would be smaller or equal to it. Similarly, `large` could be initialized with `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.